# Pushing liberty app + server to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I want to deploy a liberty application along with server config to Bluemix, I found these options listed in the documentation

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/optionsForPushing.html#options_for_pushing

My question is should we be pushing the app + server always to keep the server config, or it like push app + server for the first time and subsequent pushes can only contain app files ? will the server config be retained?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the app + server every time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to deploy Liberty on the IBM Cloud - the recommended place to get started is on the App Service console:

https://console.bluemix.net/developer/appservice/starter-kits

The documentation has options for Kubernetes / CF Deployment to the Cloud and recommend using the IBM Cloud Dev CLI tooling which containerizes your app to run locally and gives you the option to push the image up when you're ready.

In addition, starter kits set up an example of how you can incorporate DevOps into your app. When you make changes from your Git Repo, it will trigger a hook which will run the app through your testing pipelines, and deploy it to the cloud.

The idea of using containers is so you can package your application with a consistent, reproducible environment, so you can orchestrate and scale your application when necessary.

Comment: you should be able to push the app and the server at the same time.